# SCCM 2012 R2 - unknown PC boot over PXE - bcd file error

Tags: pxe-boot, wds, sccm-2012

When I want to boot an unknown PC over PXE an error comes after it starts the `boot\x64\pxeboot.n12` file. The error looks like a Windows 8 bluescreen and contains:

```
Recovery

Your PC needs to be repaired.

The Windows Boot Configuration Data (BCD) file from the PXE Server does not contain a valid operating System entry. Ensure that the Server has boot Images installed for this architecture.

File:\Tmp\x86x64{abc123}.bcd
Error code: 0x0c0000098

You´ll Need to use the recovery Tools on your media. ..
```

What could that error occur?

For your info:

I have enabled PXE on the distribution point.
I deployed a Windows 7 x64 image, also the boot.wim images and enabled the point that they are available for PXE boot.

On the dhcp server I made the entries on port 66 (ip of the sccm/pxe server) and 67 (name of boot file: `\SMSBoot\x86\wdsnbp.com`).

I made a task sequence for installing an existing Image. I configured it with the boot.wim (x64) and with the Windows 7 x64 Image for "only media and pxe".

I advertised the task sequence.

The content status of the files is successful. And i waited already a few minutes.
I tried the task sequence also with the x86 boot.wim file, but nothing was changed. I deleted the boot images from the distribution point and deployed them again - also no changes. I just took the default boot images from sccm, which where already included.

It´s frustrating I cant find the cause. I hope you can help me.

Edit:

After I changed the DHCP Option for the startfile to `\SMSBoot\x64\pxeboot example.com` and formatted the lokal drive of the client what i wanted to boot over pxe, the error turned to this:

```
Recovery

Your PC needs to be repaired.

The Windows Boot Configuration Data for your PC is missing or contains errors.

File:\Boot\BCD
Error code: 0xc000000f

You´ll Need to use the recovery Tools on your media. ..
```

When I turn the DHCP option for the startfile back, the first error shows up.

I searched for a solution for the last error, but i didnt really found a good solution for this problem. I just found something like this: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12268.troubleshooting-sccm-2012-pxe-boot-error-0xc000000f-while-installing-task-sequence.aspx
I´m not sure if i should try this solution, because i didn't update the SCCM 2012 to the SP1, that was a full Installation with SP1.

I also looked into the SMSPXE.log on the sccm server:

```
00:25:B3:17:81:81, 569953E2-0A46-11DE-BBDA-B31781810025: Not serviced.  SMSPXE  08.05.2014 11:12:42 8628 (0x21B4)
RequestMPKeyInformation: Send() failed. SMSPXE  08.05.2014 11:12:42 8628 (0x21B4)
Failed to get information for MP: example.org 80004005. SMSPXE  08.05.2014 11:12:42 8628 (0x21B4)
PXE::MP_InitializeTransport failed; 0x80004005  SMSPXE  08.05.2014 11:12:42 8628 (0x21B4)
PXE::MP_LookupDevice failed; 0x80004005 SMSPXE  08.05.2014 11:12:42 8628 (0x21B4)
RequestMPKeyInformation: Send() failed. SMSPXE  08.05.2014 11:12:42 8628 (0x21B4)
Failed to get information for MP: example.org. 80004005.    SMSPXE  08.05.2014 11:12:42 8628 (0x21B4)
PXE::MP_InitializeTransport failed; 0x80004005  SMSPXE  08.05.2014 11:12:42 8628 (0x21B4)
PXE::MP_ReportStatus failed; 0x80004005 SMSPXE  08.05.2014 11:12:42 8628 (0x21B4)
PXE Provider failed to process message. 
Unknown error (Error: 80004005; Source: Unknown)    SMSPXE  08.05.2014 11:12:42 8628 (0x21B4)
00:25:B3:17:81:81, 569953E2-0A46-11DE-BBDA-B31781810025: Not serviced.  SMSPXE  08.05.2014 11:12:42 8628 (0x21B4)
File E:\RemoteInstall\SMSTemp\2014.04.25.16.02.20.01.{F40C9975-DF1F-4F67-802A-29AD678BC3B8}.boot.bcd deleted.   SMSPXE  08.05.2014 11:12:44 46728 (0xB688)
File E:\RemoteInstall\SMSTemp\2014.04.25.16.02.20.01.{F40C9975-DF1F-4F67-802A-29AD678BC3B8}.boot.bcd.log deleted.   SMSPXE  08.05.2014 11:12:44 46728 (0xB688)
File E:\RemoteInstall\SMSTemp\2014.05.08.11.07.51.03.{EE53DA24-A9DE-4629-9C22-1EE99A960150}.boot.bcd deleted.   SMSPXE  08.05.2014 11:12:44 46728 (0xB688)
File E:\RemoteInstall\SMSTemp\2014.05.08.11.07.51.03.{EE53DA24-A9DE-4629-9C22-1EE99A960150}.boot.bcd.log deleted.   SMSPXE  08.05.2014 11:12:44 46728 (0xB688)
Boot image I0100005 has changed since added SMSPXE  08.05.2014 11:29:50 35992 (0x8C98)
Loaded D:\Microsoft\Windows Kits\8.1\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\DISM\wimgapi.dll  SMSPXE  08.05.2014 11:29:50 35992 (0x8C98)
Opening image file E:\RemoteInstall\SMSImages\I0100005\boot.I0100005.wim    SMSPXE  08.05.2014 11:29:50 35992 (0x8C98)
Found Image file: E:\RemoteInstall\SMSImages\I0100005\boot.I0100005.wim
 PackageID: I0100005
 ProductName: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
 Architecture: 9
 Description: Microsoft Windows PE (x64)
 Version:  
 Creator: 
 SystemDir: WINDOWS
SMSPXE  08.05.2014 11:29:50 35992 (0x8C98)
Closing image file E:\RemoteInstall\SMSImages\I0100005\boot.I0100005.wim    SMSPXE  08.05.2014 11:29:50 35992 (0x8C98)
File E:\RemoteInstall\SMSTemp\2014.04.25.16.02.24.02.{120C6047-D013-4481-A959-        E095D4385373}.boot.bcd deleted.   SMSPXE  08.05.2014 11:32:44 23120 (0x5A50)
File E:\RemoteInstall\SMSTemp\2014.04.25.16.02.24.02.{120C6047-D013-4481-A959-E095D4385373}.boot.bcd.log deleted.   SMSPXE  08.05.2014 11:32:44 23120 (0x5A50)
Begin validation of Certificate [Thumbprint DC4C1EAB9A23B7003FADFBD27CD2284069DFF8E6] issued to '{445FD9AA-558A-413B-9243-7AB6530FCD31}'    SMSPXE  08.05.2014 12:02:48 20392 (0x4FA8)
Completed validation of Certificate [Thumbprint DC4C1EAB9A23B7003FADFBD27CD2284069DFF8E6] issued to '{445FD9AA-558A-413B-9243-7AB6530FCD31}'    SMSPXE  08.05.2014 12:02:48 20392 (0x4FA8)
```

I'm not sure what i shall do.

Update:

After searching a solution for the `0xc000000f`error, i found an advice that i should look into the `mpcontrol.log` - there are these logfile-entries:

```
SSL is not enabled. SMS_MP_CONTROL_MANAGER  09.05.2014 12:08:04 10392 (0x2898)
Call to HttpSendRequestSync failed for port 80 with status code 404, text: Not Found    SMS_MP_CONTROL_MANAGER  09.05.2014 12:08:05 10392 (0x2898)
Sent summary record of SMS Management Point on ["Display=\\example.org\"]MSWNET:["SMS_SITE=I01"]\\example.org\ to \\example.org\SMS_I01\inboxes\sitestat.box\pywuipdu.SUM, Availability 1, 104723452 KB total disk space , 49143084 KB free disk space, installation state 0.   SMS_MP_CONTROL_MANAGER  09.05.2014 12:08:05 10392 (0x2898)
Http test request failed, status code is 404, 'Not Found'.  SMS_MP_CONTROL_MANAGER  09.05.2014 12:08:05 10392 (0x2898)
Successfully performed Management Point availability check against local computer.  SMS_MP_CONTROL_MANAGER  09.05.2014 12:08:05 10392 (0x2898)
```

Maybe i should enable SSL?

Update:
I dont know if i could fix the problem, but i am not responsible for that system anymore, so i cant try to fix it. Thank you anyway for the answers. If someone has a similar problem, vote for the right answer.

Comment: I don't know if it has anything to do with your problem but I would use the x64 boot file if you're deploying only x64 images.

Comment: Have you tried setting the bootfile to `\SMSBoot\x64\wdsnbp.com` ?

Comment: In addition to changing the bootfile name, I'll point out that you shouldn't *need* to set up either DHCP option anymore, so I'd advise trying without either option set, and seeing if you have better (or different) results.

Comment: @HopelessN00bGeniusofnetwork yes, i tried that already.

Comment: @HopelessN00bGeniusofnetwork i cant without setting the DHCP Options, because the PC is in another VLAN as the SCCM/PXE Server.

Comment: @SophiaMarie Can't use an IP-helper (sometimes called DHCP relay) address instead?

Comment: @HopelessN00bGeniusofnetwork So, you mean that it would work with a dhcp relay agent?

Comment: @SophiaMarie That's how we have it set up for an ~18 site deployment.  Works fine, without setting and DHCP options on any of our scopes.

Comment: @HopelessN00bGeniusofnetwork i installed the dhcp relay agent like this: http://patrick.eviltools.com/dhcp-server-with-dhcp-relay-agent-in-windows-2012-server/
and when i delete the port 66 and port 67 Options, there is a "pxe-e53 no bootfile received" error when the pc is starting with pxe.

Comment: @SophiaMarie Uh.. not sure you did that right.  The IP-helper/DHCP relay is a configuration on your network gear, not your SCCM server... so unless you have a Server 2012 server doing routing in your environment, you probably did that in the wrong spot.

Comment: @HopelessN00bGeniusofnetwork i installed the dhcp relay agent on the dhcp server, not on the sccm server. But you are right, that´s the wrong spot for forwarding the pxe things. I´m not sure if the Problem really causes that I use the scope Options of dhcp. It´s really weird.

Comment: What sort of hardware (laptop, desktop, other, etc.) and what vendor/make and model are we talking about here that you are trying to image?

Comment: @BradBouchard it is a hp compaq dc7900 small form factor pc (its a desktop PC)

Comment: @All
I have edited my question and added some Information. Maybe you know more about this problem now.

Comment: On our DHCP server, we do not have a leading backslash on the Bootfile Name, it just reads `smsboot\x86\wdsnbp.com`.

Answer (score 1):

This is indicative of the distribution point's SMS PXE service failing to catch a boot, and WDS instead servicing the boot request.  To verify if this is the problem , look at the \\DPServer\SMS_DP$\SMS\Logs\SMSPXE.log file.  If the last entry in the log file is

```
==========PXE Provider shutdown===========
```

and you don't see any record of recent PXE attempts, then you definitely have this issue.

### How to fix it

You just need to remove and reinstall PXE to fix this problem.  Connect to the SCCM Console, Administration\ Site and Site Systems and double click the Distribution point component for the failing DP.  On the PXE-tab, remove the top check box 'Enable PXE Support for Clients' and click apply, which will prompt  ConfigMgr to remove the PXE role.

You can watch this in the distmgr.log on the Primary server, and the SMSPXE and SMSDPPROV.logs on the DP.

Once this is finished, reboot the remote DP.  Then reinstall PXE via the same checkbox.  You may see a number of errors of

```
Opening image file
Found image file
Closing image File
InstallBootFilesForImage Failed 0x80004005 (Access Denied)
'Failed to copy the needed boot binaries from the boot image  \\server\share\BootImage.wim' 
The operation completed successfully.
Failed adding image, will retry, Unspecified error
```

Followed by dozens of `Error opening file : Imagefile.wim Win32=32'.  These errors indicate that SCCM is still copying down the boot image, after reinstall PXE.

They should smooth themselves out, and then you'll be good to go.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer, it looks good, what you've written, but i can't test it anymore.. so.. forgive me ;)